# how to give Date of Birth validation in Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement for DOB Validation. the date in date picker should be -5 years from today's date.for ex: if the registered user should give the date , when they opened the date picker it shown default 5 years back onwards. i.e (NowDate) - (5 years) = 27/1/ 2010. is this possible to do in Jquery. if anyone suggest about this.

Comment: are you using jquery datepicker ??

Comment: this is not hard to research...what have you tried? You are expected to have at least made an attempt to research and look for solutions for your problems before asking here

Comment: @shafeeq : No i am using Devexpress date Picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this one helps.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker minimumSize" name="BirthDate" id="BirthDate"  readonly="readonly"/>

var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear() - 5;
d.setFullYear(year);
$('#BirthDate').datepicker({ changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, yearRange: '1920:' + year + '', defaultDate: d});
```

[Click here for JSFIDDLE(working demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/zg8Le/248/)

Comment: Thank you so much for replying for my question, This will help to me

Comment: i have a doubt , if i am using devexpress DatePicker. how can i ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) or [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate).